# Why are non-exported types implicitly exported from a TS declaration file with imports but no exports? Is this a bug?

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

Why are non-exported types implicitly exported from a TS declaration file with imports but no exports? Is this a bug? If not, what is this behavior called and is it documented anywhere?

#### Background:

I understand that in a TS declaration files with no imports or exports every declaration becomes ambient, and is available without imports.

In a declaration file with ECMAScript module exports, types from the file are only available from other files if they are explicitly exported.

There seems to be a **third** behavior of TS declaration files that have at least one import or export statement but no export declarations: Any variable/function/interface etc. declaration in such a file can be imported from other files, even though they weren't explicitly exported.

#### Example:

**weird.d.ts** (imports from self)

```
import {} from "./weird";
declare const implicitlyExposed: {};
```

**importer.d.ts**

```
import { implicitlyExposed } from "./weird"; // no error, is usable import
```

#### Clarification

Note that unexported declarations are only leaked from a .d.ts file that is a module if there are no export declarations. An export declaration looks like this:

```
declare const foo: number;
export { foo };
```

TS treats such an export differently from a statement with an export modifier:

```
export declare const foo: number;
```

Using the former syntax prevents non-exported declarations from being importable from other files.

Comment: That's the same behavior as with a module with exports.

Comment: Whoa! How did I not know this? What's going on? Does this mean that everything in a declaration file is implicitly exported? What is the difference between using/not-using the `export` keyword?

Comment: @ritaj, the existence of an export declaration changes the behavior. I updated the question to explain.